# Boost vector insert_element one by one error

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I have following piece of code; I am getting conversion error, please tell me where I am going wrong?
Basically I am adding element one by one in vector after some proceesing for that value.

Doubt: I want to add new element at the end of vector so is traingleVertex.end() in argument is correct?

```
 typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>  Rd;
    Rd boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>;

    //some code for Mn
    triangleVertex.insert_element(triangleVertex.end(), Mn);
    //some code for Ln
    triangleVertex.insert_element(triangleVertex.end(), Ln);
```

> ```
> error C2664: 'boost_1_53_0::numeric::ublas::vector<T>::insert_element'
> ```
>
> : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'boost_1_53_0::numeric::ublas::vector::iterator' to 'unsigned
>   __int64'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ublas::vector<T>::insert_element` expects a `size_type` as it's first argument and not an iterator.

Use:

```
triangleVertex.insert_element(triangleVertex.size(), Mn);
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm)

Comment: thanks, now its working properly. I think, I can also write triangleVertex.end()-triangleVertex.begin().

Answer (score 0):

As pmr shows, `insert_element` expects an index into the vector. It seems to me that what you want is *adding* some element at the end of the vector. This is not efficient in a vector, and you should instead try to know beforehand the size of the vector, and add the element at the correct position with `insert_element`.